# IBM Insights for Twitterデモのソースコードはありますか?

Tags: bluemix, twitter

IBM Insights for Twitterの[デモアプリ](https://cdetestapp.mybluemix.net/)のソースコードはどこかで公開されていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらに公開されているようです。

sample-cdetestapp
https://hub.jazz.net/project/kungr/sample-cdetestapp/overview

Comment: 苦言：「cdetestapp」で検索すれば見つかりました。bluemix関連のQ&Aは低品質なものが多いように見受けられます。